# Android how to populate details in adapter by using arraylist of modal class

Tags: java, android

I am using recyclerview in my project and i have to populate different list of data in recycler item so i created different model class for each list and integrated as a single modelclass now i want to populate all the list items in recyclerview

Here is the arraylist of modelclass list

```
 ArrayList profileArr =new ArrayList();
 profileArr.add(profileDataList);
 profileArr.add(userWorksClassList);
 profileArr.add(userEducationClassList);
 profileArr.add(userSportsClassList);
 profileArr.add(userDanceClassList);
 profileArr.add(userMusicClassList);
 profileArr.add(userMusicInstruClassList);
 profileArr.add(userHobbiesClassList);
 profileArr.add(userClubClassList);
 profileArr.add(userEmergencyContClassList);
 profileArr.add(userBloodGroupClassList);
```

Here i am passing values into adapter

```
 ProfileUiAdapter profileUiAdapter=new
 ProfileUiAdapter(profileArr,profileTitle);
```

this is the code i am trying to get values in my adapter class

```
 private ArrayList profileArr;
 private List<String> profileTitle;
 Object profile;

 if(position==0){
    profile = profileArr.get(position);
    ProfileMainmod profileMainmod= (ProfileMainmod) profile;
    String strEmail=profileMainmod.email;
    Log.e("profile", strEmail);
 }
```

I expect the output like strEmail should contain the value from the arraylist.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? this looks fine, so where does it crash, or not work as expected, and what happends?

Comment: its saying array cannot be cast to modelclass

Comment: String strEmail=profileMainmod.email; this line is getting arralist cannot be cast to model class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right, so it seems like you are actually creating an arraylist containing other lists

```
ArrayList profileArr =new ArrayList();
 profileArr.add(profileDataList);
```

profileDataList is an arraylsit of ProfileMainmod objects?

so this code should work:

```
ArrayList<ProfileMainmod> profileList = (ArrayList<ProfileMainmod>)profileArr.get(position);
ProfileMainmod profileMainmod= (ProfileMainmod) profileList.get(0);
```

but you need to decide and/or explain how to handle the indexes in the lists.

Comment: sorry for late reply